# Win32 Can't get data from shared memory

Tags: c++, shared-memory

I am able to create a shared memory object, as well as open it using the guide from MSDN.

The first process creates it and keeps it open.
The second process inputs a string.
Then the first process will attempt to recover that string and display it, however I can't seem to get anything. It's always empty although it seems like the writing part is set up correctly.

I write a string to memory like this:

```
int MemoryMapper::Write(const std::string& data) {

    m_pBuffer = (LPCTSTR)MapViewOfFile(m_OpenHandle, FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, 0, 0, m_BufferSize);

    if (m_pBuffer == NULL)
    {
        std::cerr << m_DebugErrorTitle << "Write(): " << MM_ERROR_MAPPING_FAILED << " {" << GetLastError() << "}" << std::endl;
        Close();
        return 0;
    }

    const char* cdata = _CharFromString(data);
    int size = (lstrlen(cdata) * sizeof(const char*));

    CopyMemory((PVOID)m_pBuffer, cdata, size);
    m_WrittenSize += size;

    if (m_Debug > 1) { std::cout << m_DebugTitle << "Wrote " << size << " bytes." << std::endl; }
    return size;
}
```

Then I read it like so:

```
int MemoryMapper::Read(std::string& data) {

    m_pBuffer = (LPCTSTR) MapViewOfFile(m_OpenHandle, FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, 0, 0, m_BufferSize);

    if (m_pBuffer == NULL)
    {
        std::cerr << m_DebugErrorTitle << "Read(" << m_MemoryName << "): " << MM_ERROR_MAPPING_FAILED << " {" << GetLastError() << "}" << std::endl;
        Close();
        return 0;
    }

    MessageBox(NULL, m_pBuffer, TEXT("TEST MESSAGE"), MB_OK);

    int size = (lstrlen(m_pBuffer) * sizeof(const char*));
    UnmapViewOfFile(m_pBuffer);
    return size;
}
```

m_pBuffer is a LPCTSTR and m_BufferSize is 1024.
The name speficied for the object is the same on both ends. I've already made sure the creation and opening/closing part works.

The second process writes '8312.000000,8312.000000', a total of 92 bytes according to the code.

The reader's buffer is empty.

What am I doing wrong?
I've tried various data types, char, const char, string, tchar - same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`8312.000000,8312.000000` is 23 characters in length.

`std::string::c_str()` returns a null-terminated `char*` pointer.  `lstrlen()` returns the number of characters up to but not including the null terminator.

`Write()` is multiplying the string length by `sizeof(const char*)`, which is 4 in a 32-bit process (8 in a 64-bit process).  `Write()` is exceeding the bounds of `data` and attempting to copy `23 * 4 = 92` bytes into `m_pBuffer`.  `cdata` is guaranteed to point at a buffer containing `24` bytes max (23 characters + 1 null terminator), so `Write()` is reaching into surrounding memory.  That is *undefined behavior*, and *anything* could happen.  In your case, you probably just ended up copying extra garbage into `m_pBuffer`.  `Write()` could have easily crashed instead.

In fact, if `data` has more than 256 characters, `Write()` WOULD crash, because it would be trying to copy `257+ * 4 > 1024` bytes into `m_pBuffer` - more than `MapViewOfFile()` mapped access for.

You should be multiplying the string length by `sizeof(std::string::value_type)` instead, which is `sizeof(char)`, which is always 1 (so you could just omit the multiplication).

`Read()` has the same `sizeof()` mistake, but it is also making the assumption that `m_pBuffer` is always null-terminated when calling `lstrlen()` and `MessageBox()`, but `Write()` does not guarantee that a null terminator is always present.

With that said, try something more like this instead:

```
int MemoryMapper::Write(const std::string& data)
{
    // include the null terminator if there is room...
    DWORD size = std::min(data.size() + 1, m_BufferSize);

    char *pBuffer = (char*) MapViewOfFile(m_OpenHandle, FILE_MAP_WRITE, 0, 0, size);
    if (!pBuffer)
    {
        DWORD errCode = GetLastError();
        std::cerr << m_DebugErrorTitle << "Write(): " << MM_ERROR_MAPPING_FAILED << " {" << errCode << "}" << std::endl;
        Close();
        return 0;
    }

    CopyMemory(pBuffer, data.c_str(), size);
    UnmapViewOfFile(pBuffer);

    m_WrittenSize += size;

    if (m_Debug > 1) {
        std::cout << m_DebugTitle << "Wrote " << size << " bytes." << std::endl;
    }

    return size;
}

int MemoryMapper::Read(std::string& data)
{
    char *pBuffer = (char*) MapViewOfFile(m_OpenHandle, FILE_MAP_READ, 0, 0, m_BufferSize);
    if (!pBuffer)
    {
        DWORD errCode = GetLastError();
        std::cerr << m_DebugErrorTitle << "Read(" << m_MemoryName << "): " << MM_ERROR_MAPPING_FAILED << " {" << errCode << "}" << std::endl;
        Close();
        return 0;
    }

    // check for a null terminator, but don't exceed the buffer...
    char *terminator = std::find(pBuffer, pBuffer + m_BufferSize, '\0');
    std::size_t len = std::distance(pBuffer, terminator);

    data.assign(pBuffer, len);
    UnmapViewOfFile(pBuffer);

    MessageBoxA(NULL, data.c_str(), "TEST MESSAGE", MB_OK);

    // include the null terminator if it was read...
    return std::min(len + 1, m_BufferSize);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your good explanation. I've implemented the changes according to your suggestion, and the write takes place with 24 bytes, however I am still unable to read it. No message is received.

Comment: Actually, there was a remaining mistake with the different shared memories' naming, and now it works using your guidance. Thank you very much.